# How to compile with a static library that relies on another static library

Tags: c++, amqp

How do I compile a code with a static library that relies on boost and another static library?

I've tried

```
g++ -lSimpleAmqpClient test_simpleamqpclient.cpp -o test_simpleamqpclient
```

and

```
g++ -lrabbitmq -lSimpleAmqpClient test_simpleamqpclient.cpp -o test_simpleamqpclient
```

**test_simpleamqpclient.cpp**

```
#include "SimpleAmqpClient/SimpleAmqpClient.h"

int main(){
    AmqpClient::BasicMessage::ptr_t message = AmqpClient::BasicMessage::Create();
    return 0;
}
```

**/usr/local/include/SimpleAmqpClient/SimpleAmqpClient.h**

```
:
#include "SimpleAmqpClient/BasicMessage.h"
:
```

I'm getting

```
/tmp/ccMsTz9s.o: In function `boost::detail::sp_if_not_array<AmqpClient::BasicMessage>::type boost::make_shared<AmqpClient::BasicMessage>()':
test_simpleamqpclient.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost11make_sharedIN10AmqpClient12BasicMessageEEENS_6detail15sp_if_not_arrayIT_E4typeEv[_ZN5boost11make_sharedIN10AmqpClient12BasicMessageEEENS_6detail15sp_if_not_arrayIT_E4typeEv]+0x62): undefined reference to `AmqpClient::BasicMessage::BasicMessage()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The static library, *libSimpleAmqpClient.a*.

**libSimpleAmqpClient.pc**

```
prefix=/usr/local
exec_prefix=${prefix}
libdir=${exec_prefix}/lib
includedir=${prefix}/include

Name: SimpleAmqpClient
Description: C++ wrapper of rabbitmq-c AMQP client library
Version: 2.5.0
Requires.private: librabbitmq
Libs: -L${libdir} -lSimpleAmqpClient
Libs.private:  -L/usr/local/lib -lboost_chrono -lboost_system
CFlags: -I${includedir}
```

It relies on *boost* and another library, *librabbitmq.a*

**librabbitmq.pc**

```
prefix=/usr/local
exec_prefix=${prefix}
libdir=${exec_prefix}/lib64
includedir=${prefix}/include

Name: rabbitmq-c
Description: An AMQP 0-9-1 client library
Version: 0.8.1
URL: https://github.com/alanxz/rabbitmq-c
Requires.private:
Libs: -L${libdir} -lrabbitmq
Libs.private: rt;-lpthread
CFlags: -I${includedir}
```

Comment: Static libraries AFAIK do not contain any dependency information. There's just a list of unresolved symbols which need to be resolved. Thus one has to specify all static libraries directly during linking.

Comment: @DanielJour Example codes that came with `librabbitmq.a` compiles and runs correctly. However, I can't say the same with `libSimpleAmqpClient.a`. Is there a way to verify that it was statically build correctly (and has no dependency to other library)?

Comment: Not completely sure, but `nm -u lib.a` should show unresolved symbols.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out, even though you're linking with a static library, you still need to link with the library dependencies. I've manage to compile it with this syntax

```
g++ test_simpleamqpclient.cpp -o test_simpleamqpclient -lSimpleAmqpClient -lboost_chrono -lboost_system -lrabbitmq -lrt -lssl
```

Hope this will help someone.

Comment: I also needed `-lcrypto -ldl -lpthread` in order to make SimpleAmqpClient to work